# XSLT: How to split a file into multiple files and use elements in the source file?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have a lengthy file converted from JSON to XML, at my request. I want to split it into multiple files based on an element called "object" and use "object/name", a child element, as the filename.  There are no attributes in the file that I can use.  All the examples I've found use some sort of ID attribute.  In the example below, I'd like the output file to contain all the "object" data, including element tags. The output file should be "NewMethod.xml"

Thanks for any help you can give.

A truncated example (original is very lengthy) of a single object node is:

```
<objects>
<object>
    <operations>
        <operation>create</operation>
    </operations>
    <enums>
    </enums>
    <name>NewMethod</name>
    <parent />
    <fields>
        <field>
            <create_required>true</create_required>
            <name>name</name>
            <datatype />
            <is_immutable>false</is_immutable>
            <enum_type />
            <is_list>false</is_list>
            <rest_revision>0</rest_revision>
            <range />
            <is_read_only>false</is_read_only>
            <null_value />
            <dict_key />
            <object_types />
            <type>string</type>
            <compound_type />
        </field>
        <fields>
            <ref_pattern>/abc/abc-{method_id}</ref_pattern>
            <ids>
                <id>method_id</id>
            </ids>
            <ref_create_pattern>/abc/abc-new</ref_create_pattern>
            <compounds>
            </compounds>
            <rest_revision>0</rest_revision>
            <alias_of />
            <children>
                <child>childa</child>
                <child>childb</child>
            </children>
            <delete_rest_revision>0</delete_rest_revision>
            <ref_collection_pattern>/abc</ref_collection_pattern>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Process all `object` elements and create a result document e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//object"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
  <xsl:result-document href="{name}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```